# Apache2 “configtest failed” (error line 216, 5, 62)

Tags: server, apache2

- Starting web server apache2
- The apache2 configtest failed.

Output of config test was:

```
apache2: 
Syntax error on **line 216** of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 
Syntax error on **line 5** of /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/zz010_psa_httpd.conf: 
Syntax error on **line 62** of /etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/server.conf: 
Could not open config directory /etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/ip_default: 
No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks so much!

Comment: You haven't change anything on `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` right ?

Comment: Hi Liso, thank you for your reply. No I haven't changed anything on /etc/apache2/apache2.conf .

Comment: Please share the following configs: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/zz010_psa_httpd.conf /etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/server.conf Share the configs pls on this site: https://paste.ubuntu.com/ This file is missing: `/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/ip_default:` Do you have Plesk installed?

Answer (score 0):

Try open `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` using gedit :

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

And then replace this line

```
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock
```

With this one

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
```

Comment: This may very well be an excellent answer, but could you please explain why you think this will solve the problem? E.g. why is there a LockFile statement while a Mutex statement is missing? Or do you have any other source where this is given as the solution?

Comment: I tried it and this was the respone:The apache2 configtest failed.

Output of config test was:

apache2: 

Syntax error on line 215 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 

Syntax error on line 5 of /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/zz010_psa_httpd.conf: 

Syntax error on line 62 of /etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/server.conf: 

Could not open config directory /etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/ip_default: 

No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.

Comment: Does anyone know what I should do?